# Use printf with multiple variables in Java

Tags: java, printf

Whenever I use this, it only prints out the first two variables.

This is my code:
`out.printf("%9d %s%n", jobs.new, jobs.old, jobs.all, jobs.welcome, allnames);`

Answer (score 4):

You need a placeholder for all variables.
`out.printf("%9d %9d %9d %9d %s%n", jobs.new, jobs.old, jobs.all, jobs.welcome, allnames);`